# How to make my JavaScript more maintainable?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript so sorry if the question appears basic.

I made User interface tour, script is working as i want but it is hard to maintain and do any changes.

**Q:** How to loop the steps so i will just need to add Step title and description and not be bothered with linking between functions?

Any more suggestions to make script better practice?

Thanks in advance.

**Link to script:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gmajsterek/4ar2vvro/15/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var title = " ",
    description = " ";

$(".UserGuideModal").hide();

$("#ShowHomeUserGuide").click(function () {
    step1();

});

function guideModal() {
    $("#btnNextTip").attr("disabled", false);
    // User Guide Modal Content
    $(".modal-title").html(title);
    $(".guideDescription").html(description);
}

// Close btn
$(".btn-closewindow").click(function () {
    $(".ugoutline").removeClass("ugoutline");
    $(".step4").removeClass("ugoutline");
    $(".UserGuideModal").hide(300);

});


function step1() {
    $(".UserGuideModal").show(300);
    title = "Step one title",
    description = "Description 1";
    $(".step1").addClass("ugoutline");
    guideModal();
    $("#btnNextTip").click(function () {
        step2();

    });
}


function step2() {

    title = "Step two title",
    description = "Description 2";
    $(".step1").removeClass("ugoutline");
    $(".step4").removeClass("ugoutline");
    $(".step2").addClass("ugoutline");
    guideModal();

    $("#btnNextTip").click(function () {

        $(".step2").removeClass("ugoutline");
        step3();

    });

}

function step3() {

    title = "Step three title",
    description = "Description 3";
    $(".step3").addClass("ugoutline");
    $(".step4").removeClass("ugoutline");
    guideModal();

    $("#btnNextTip").click(function () {
        $(".step3").removeClass("ugoutline");
        step4();
    });

}

function step4() {
    title = "Step four title",
    description = "Description 4";
    $(".step4").addClass("ugoutline");
    guideModal();
    $(".btn-closewindow").click(function () {

        $(".step4").removeClass("ugoutline");
        $(".UserGuideModal").hide(300);
    });

    $("#btnNextTip").attr("disabled", true);
}

    });
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Once you get a bit more familiar with JS, have a look at http://facebook.github.io/react/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having each step exist as a function, you should break it up by data and behavior.

I would recommend using:

An array to store step information. e.g.

`var steps = [{name: "step1", title: "Step 1", description: "Description 1"}, {name: "step2", title: "Step 2", description: "Description 2"},...]`

A function to highlight the appropriate row div. e.g.

```
var highlightLabel = function(labelClass){
    $(".stepLabel").removeClass("ugoutline");
    $("."+labelClass).addClass("ugoutline");
} //assuming each of your step1, step2... classes also has the class stepLabel
```

A single function to handle step display

```
var showStep = function(stepIndex){
    $(".modal-title").html(steps[stepIndex].title);
    $(".guideDescription").html(steps[stepIndex].description);
    highlightLabel(steps[stepIndex].name);
    $("#ShowHomeUserGuide").click();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take anything in the `stepX()` functions that's DIFFERENT between the various versions and turn that into a function parameter.

e.g.

```
function step(stepNumber) {
    $('.step' + (stepNumber -1)).removeClass('ugoutline');
    $('.step' + stepNumber).addClass('ugoutline"');
    step(stepNumber + 1);
}
```

pass in `4`, you'll do a removeClass on 4-1 = ".step3", and do an addClass on `.step4`.